# Is it possible to work around SQLcipher by modifying libsqlcipher.so?

Tags: android

I was trying to extract data from an Android app which uses SQLcipher. SQLcipher is an extension of SQLite that encrypts database files with 256-bit AES.

Within the APK, the library lies in `lib/libsqlcipher.so`. I'm curious if I can extract the encryption key simply by modifying `libsqlcipher.so`(e.g. modify `sqlite3_key` function so that it logs the encryption key to file). The plan is to compile my own version of `libsqlcipher.so`, repack APK, install it, and run it on a device.

Will this method work as expected? It sounds too easy to be true:)

Comment: It will work, you don't need modifing the library, you can use some sort of dynamic instrumentation like Frida.